# Projection of a point to a convex hull in d dimensions

Tags: computational-geometry

Hi,

I've got n points in d dimensions (typically n is around 30k-60k and d is 5 or 6). I'm using qhull to calculate the Delaunay triangulation and the convex hull of the set of points.

You can assume each point was drawn from the normal multidimensional distribution. I need the triangulation for function interpolation which works quite well once you calculate the simplex/barycentric coordinates of the query point p.

The problem is how to handle points that are outside the convex hull (which occurs fairly infrequently - but does occur)? I need a way to project the point onto the hull's surface and calculate where on the d-1 dimensional face it hit so that I can interpolate this point  (essentially clipping the point to the region of the hull).

Is there an efficient algorithm out there that does this? I came across [this](http://www.csd.uwo.ca/~vmazalov/pubs/2012-eccad-distance-to-simplex.pdf) on the web but am not clear how to apply it across the entire hull efficiently.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The natural projection of your exterior point $a$ is to the point $b$ on the polytope that is
closest to $a$, i.e., which minimizes the distance $|ab|$.  This can be formulated as a [quadratic
programming problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_programming), for which there are many algorithms.

Quite some time ago, Gilbert worked out some methods:

> (1) E. G. Gilbert,  "Minimizing the quadratic form on a convex set",  *SIAM J. Contr.*,  vol. 4,  pp.61-79 1966
>
> (2) E. G. Gilbert, D. W. Johnson, and S. S. Keerthi,  "A fast procedure for computing the distance between complex objects in three dimensional space",  *IEEE J. Robot. Automat.*,  vol. 4,  pp.193-203 1988 ([PDF link](http://graphics.stanford.edu/courses/cs448b-00-winter/papers/gilbert.pdf))

The first sentence of the 2nd paper above is: "An efficient and reliable algorithm for computing
the Euclidean distance between a pair of convex sets in $\mathbb{R}^m$ is described."  This algorithm has become known as the *GJK algorithm*.

I doubt this is the last word on the topic.  There is a huge literature on collision detection in
$\mathbb{R}^3$—which often amounts to finding the minimum distance from a point to a polyhedron—but I don't know how much of it scales gracefully to dimensions $5$ or $6$.

Answer (score 1):

I found a very simple [algorithm](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1101.6081.pdf) that returns the barycentric coordinates of an arbitrary point in n dimensions - so what I've done is to find all the outermost simplexes (in qhull you just check that at least 1 entry in the neighbours list is -1) - and by brute force check the distance from the query point (in each simplexes barycentric coordinates) to the simplex's projection and pick the smallest one.